# Merge two rows in SQL with only one column being different

Tags: sql, join, union

Assuming I have a table containing the following information:

```
FK | Field1 | Field2
---+--------+--------
4  | 103    | 5836
4  | 103    | 5835

FK | Field1 | Field2 | Field2A
---+--------+--------+--------
4  | 103    | 5836   | 5835
```

Thanks

Comment: I think that there is no a standard way to do this. It will depend of the database you are working.

Comment: and field2 can reach up to field2Z?   you might want to have a look at PIVOT

Comment: any example please?

Answer (score 0):

i think you really need PIVOT, but for an exact dataset in the question, you can follow an approach like below, it's kinda weird and in T-SQl:

```
declare @a as int
declare @b as int
declare @c as int
declare @query Varchar(Max)

set @query = 'Select 4,103'
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR   
select * From
(select 4 as a , 103 as b   , 5836 as c
Union select 4 as a , 103 as b   , 5835 as c) as res

OPEN curs  

FETCH NEXT FROM curs   
INTO @a,@b,@c
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
set @query = @query + ','+cast(@c as varchar)

FETCH NEXT FROM curs   
INTO @a,@b,@c

END
CLOSE curs;  
DEALLOCATE curs;
EXEC(@query)
```